# Select latest row on duplicate values while transfering table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a logging table that is live which saves my value to a table frequently.

My plan is to take those values and put them on a temporary table with

```
SELECT * INTO #temp from Block
```

From there I guess my block table is empty and the logger can keep on logging new values.

The next step is that I want to save them in a existing table. I wanted to use

```
INSERT INTO TABLENAME(COLUMN1,COLUMN2...) SELECT (COLUMN1,COLUMN2...) FROM #temp
```

The problem is that the `#temp` table has duplicates primary keys. And I only want to store the last ID.

I have tried `DISTINCT` but it didn't work. Could not get `ROW_Count` to work.  Are there any ideas on how I should do it? I wish to make it with as few reads as possible.

Also, in the future I plan to send them to another database, how do I do that on SQL Server? I guess it's something like `FROM Table [in databes]`?

I couldn't get the blocks to copy. But here goes:

```
create TABLE Product_log (
    Grade char(64),
    block_ID char(64) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    Density char(64), 
    BatchNumber char(64) NOT NULL,
    BlockDateID Datetime 
);
```

That is my table i want to store the data in. There I do not wish to have duplicates on the id. The problem is, while logging I get duplicates since I log on change. Lets say that the batchid is 1, if it becomes 2 while logging. I will get a blockid twice, both with batch number 1 and 2. How do I pick the latter?

Hope I explained enough for guidance. While logging they look like this:

```
id  SiemensTiaV15_s71200_BatchTester_NewBatchIDValue_VALUE  SiemensTiaV15_s71200_BatchTester_TestWriteValue_VALUE   SiemensTiaV15_s71200_BatchTester_TestWriteValue_TIMESTAMP   SiemensTiaV15_s71200_MainTank_Density_VALUE SiemensTiaV15_s71200_MainTank_Grade_VALUE
1   00545                                                               S0047782                                                            2020-06-09 11:18:44.583 0                                                                   xxxxx    
2   00545                                                               S0047783                                                            2020-06-09 11:18:45.800 0                                                                   xxxxx
```

Comment: Duplicate primary keys???

Comment: When you "SELECT * into #temp" you will not DELETE anything from your original table. Please add sample data to your post (as text).  Because a duplicate primary key is not possible.

Comment: Provide proper column names ans the values, so that can work on query

Comment: first of all, thanks for the answers. I think I explained my problem poorly. It will be a primary key once I pick the latest duplicate. I will edit my thread, might take some time.

Comment: Is it sufficient? @JimMacaulay and @Wouter? :)

Comment: Hm, why does it clear my original table? @Wouter 
Feels weird. Is it possible to clear the table or should I  simply truncate the table after selecting ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use below query,

```
select * from 
(select id, SiemensTiaV15_s71200_BatchTester_NewBatchIDValue_VALUE,SiemensTiaV15_s71200_BatchTester_TestWriteValue_VALUE, SiemensTiaV15_s71200_BatchTester_TestWriteValue_TIMESTAMP, SiemensTiaV15_s71200_MainTank_Density_VALUE,SiemensTiaV15_s71200_MainTank_Grade_VALUE,
row_number() over (partition by SiemensTiaV15_s71200_BatchTester_NewBatchIDValue_VALUE   order by SiemensTiaV15_s71200_BatchTester_TestWriteValue_TIMESTAMP desc) as rnk
from table_name) qry
where rnk=1;



INTO #temp FROM Block; INSERT INTO Product_log(Grade, block_ID, Density, BatchNumber, BlockDateID) 
selct NewBatchIDValue_VALUE, TestWriteValue_VALUE, TestWriteValue_TIMESTAMP, 
Density_VALUE, Grade_VALUE from
(select NewBatchIDValue_VALUE, TestWriteValue_VALUE, 
TestWriteValue_TIMESTAMP, Density_VALUE, Grade_VALUE, row_number() over 
(partition by BatchTester_NewBatchIDValue_VALUE order by 
BatchTester_TestWriteValue_VALUE) as rnk from #temp) qry
 where rnk = 1;
```

Comment: First of all, sorry for a poorly asked question. Trying to become better at asking question but it takes practice. 

Tried it, did not work as I wished. I wanted it to remove the duplicates of "SiemensTiaV15_s71200_BatchTester_TestWriteValue_VALUE " and keep the rest. I can't seem to get what the first partion by does, my guess is that it "divides" it to a new table or am I worng?

Comment: Wow, I'm so poor at this. I Just realized what you did. How do i "unselect" max rnk?

Comment: remove desc in order by clause

Comment: I am trying to get it to work but cant get it to work. Tried this : 

 INTO #temp FROM Block;

 INSERT INTO Product_log(Grade, block_ID, Density, BatchNumber, BlockDateID, rnk)
 select  NewBatchIDValue_VALUE, TestWriteValue_VALUE, TestWriteValue_TIMESTAMP, Density_VALUE, Grade_VALUE,
 row_number() over (partition by BatchTester_NewBatchIDValue_VALUE order by BatchTester_TestWriteValue_VALUE) as rnk from #temp where rnk = 1;

filtered away siemens name infront of every column.

Comment: What issue are you getting

Comment: It says that rnk is invalid column name.

Comment: Provided you insert query. Please use it

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to make the rnk choose  max rnk available ? :)

Comment: Yes based on order by clause

Comment: Was it helpful?

Comment: Yes it really was, I think you helped a lot ! Now I need to make other things work but have to try, I'm new with databases so its really hard! Had one course with MYSQL but it differs alot.